# Arrumando tds dentro de tr

Tags: css, html5

**Bom dia!** Pessoal, ainda preciso melhorar minhas skills em  `HTMl` e `CSS`. Estou fazendo uma ata de reunião e estou tendo dificuldade em alinhar umas `TD's` que ficam dentro de uma table a `TD` fica aparecendo do lado da `TR` segue código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .tabela1,
  .th1,
  .th2,
  .th3,
  .th4,
  .th5,
  .th6,
  .th7,
  .th8,
  .th9,
  .th10,
  .th11 {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .tabela2 {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tabela3 {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tabela4 {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .tr1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    margin: ;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .tr2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
  }
  
  .tr3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collpase: collapse;
  }
  
  .tr4 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .tr5 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .tr6 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tr7 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tr8 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  .h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100px;
  }
  
  .center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 18px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<img class="center" alt="Empresas do Grupo Barão de Mauá" src="https://intranet.baraodemaua.br/files/images/layout/topo.png" class="img-responsive">
<hr width="auto" size="1" color=DarkGreen>
<h4 class="h4"> ATA DE REUNIAO</h4>
<hr width="auto" size="5" color="DarkGreen">
<table class="tabela1">
  <tr class="tr1">
    <th class="th1">AREA EMITENTE</th>
    <th class="th2">LOCAL</th>
    <th class="th3">DATA</th>
    <th class="th4">HORA</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="tr2">
    <td>TI-Sistemas</td>
    <td>Reitoria - Sala de Reuniao</td>
    <td>04/07/2018</td>
    <td>14:30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<table class="tabela2">
  <tr class="tr3">
    <td class="td1"><strong>Agenda: Melhorias no Sistema de Fiscais para o proximo vestibular</strong>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<table class="tabela3">
  <tr class="tr4">
    <th rowspan="2">Participantes Fixos:
      <br>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr5">
    <td rowspan="2">Leandro Netto Scatolin
      <br> Cristiano Consule
      <br> Joyce Maria Worschech Gabrielli
      <br> Evelyn Scaramal Raphaloski
      <br>
    </td>
    <th>Participantes Convidados:</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<hr width="auto%" size="2" color=DarkGreen>
<table class="tabela4">
  <tr class="tr6">
    <th rowspan="2"><strong> Assuntos discutidos</strong></th>
    <br>

    <th> <small>I= Informacao</small></th>
    <th> <small>D= Decisao</small></th>
    <th> <small>A = Acao</small></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr7">
    <th><strong>Responsavel pela</strong></th>
    <th><small>Acao/Decisao/Informacao</small></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr8">
    <td> Criar mecanismo par indentificar fiscais que estavam
      <br>na distribuicao e foram retirados, para permitir o envio de e-mail pelo sistema,
      <br>avisando que o mesmo nao participara mais do vestibular.
      <br> TI- Desenvolvimento
      <br> Comite - Definicao de texto do e-mail</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>TI/COMITE</td>
    <td> A definir</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Jovem qual TD que está no local errado? No geral parece bem organizado o layout, poderia dar mais detalhes de onde é o problema e de como vc quer que fiquem as coisas ?

Comment: Cara poderia detalhar melhor onde esta  errado! 
Ou adicionar um exemplo de como você  espera que ficasse.

Answer (score 0):

Como não foi especificado qual tabela que você está tendo problema, mas analisando eu entendi que você está tendo problema na tabela com "Participantes fixos" e "Participantes Convidados". Caso seja realmente esse seu problema (não conseguir alinhar th com trs nessa table) o problema pode ser resolvido assim:

```html
<table class="tabela3">
  <tr class="tr4">
    <th>Participantes Fixos:</th>
    <th>Participantes Convidados:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr5">
  <td>Leandro Netto Scatolin
    <br> Cristiano Consule
    <br> Joyce Maria Worschech Gabrielli
    <br> Evelyn Scaramal Raphaloski
    <br>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Caso seja realmente esse o problema foi que você colocou um dos th na tr errada e as rowspans estavam atrapalhando também. Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: entendeu certo ufa! Desculpa

Comment: Obrigado agora  só preciso centrarlizar o resto !

Comment: Naada, qualquer dúvida só chamar